# Laravel 5 - $request->file returns null

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel-5

I'm sending some images from an angularjs client to a laravel server. Debugging the image data shows that it's a correct object, but someshow Laravel can't process it with

`$request->file('uploaded_file')`.

Logging `$scope.upload` shows

[image]

Then I send `$scope.upload[0]` as a post data to the server via `$http`.

```
data: {
    uploaded_file: $scope.upload[0]
}
```

On Laravel, what I did was:

```
$files = $request->file('uploaded_file');
dd($files);
```

Which returns `null`. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

If your post looks like my code then it will be all right.
I think that you send the selected file directly.And don't pass it through the
new FormData();

```
$scope.fileChanged = function(event) {

    var file = event.target.files[0];
    console.log(file);
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('file', file);
    $http.post("test.php",fd, {
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined,'Process-Data': false}
    }).success(function(responseData) {
        console.log(responseData);
    });
}
```

Comment: can you explain a bit more ? Why `FormData()` is necessary ?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed The FormData interface provides a way to easily construct a set of key/value pairs representing form fields and their values, which can then be easily sent using the XMLHttpRequest.send() method. It uses the same format a form would use if the encoding type were set to "multipart/form-data".

An object implementing FormData can directly be used in a for...of structure, instead of entries(): for (var p of myFormData) is equivalent to for (var p of myFormData.entries()).